# PHP permission denied for managing files

Tags: php, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I have the following test page

```
mkdir('test');

$f = fopen('test.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($f, 'gibberish');
fclose($f);

unlink('test2.txt');
```

Nothing of that happens and I get the following error messages on `erro.log`

```
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test.php on line 10
PHP Warning:  unlink(teste2.txt): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 12
```

I can clearly see that I'm having permission issues, but I have no ideia what sort of permission it is and how do I even set that kind of permission.

Using git or terminal I can create/delete/chmod all files and directories without a problem. It's just PHP that can't.

Comment: Are you running it through a web server? When running PHP through a web server, it's the user that the web server is using that needs the permissions. For Apache, it's normally `www-data`.

Comment: well, first of all: which user *owns* the files/folders? if it is not the same user as your web server process, you have your problem. go read up about how unix file systems work.

Comment: please note: using chmod 777 is always a bad idea, even for testing, it creates a false sense of having a solution and is often forgotten, while introducing potential security risks.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the chmod 777 and it worked, but I was about to ask specific about that security issue

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah. Running on Web server

Comment: @FranzGleichmann how do I see how owns the files? Never done that before

Comment: Go to you folder and type: ls -la

Comment: If you run `ls -l` in the folder above, you will see who own's that folder.

Comment: Oh, yeah. All files that weren't chmoded belong to `www-data`. The rest belongs to `root`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh using your terminal and, first, change the files owner to apache group

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

Next allow all members of this group to read and write files

```
chmod -R g+rw /var/www/html/
```

This should fix your issue. I strongly suggest you read more about permissions in ubuntu though